# Getting an error creating SQL Function (cannot convert to int) when no ints are expected

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am needing to grab data from one table and use a relationship to place it into another table. Long story short, I need to get back an array of IDs so I created a function to return them. I am only retrieving data which is IDs so all int values. The problem is when I invoke my function I get the error:
**Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '/' to data type int.**

But everything is cast as varchar so I have NO idea why this is happening. I know its dirty code but it is a high priority project with a tight deadline so I just need it to work. I am using SQL Server 2012. Any thoughts?

**Function:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION FactPersonList (@FactID varchar(100),
@delimiter char(1))

RETURNS varchar(8000)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @CharIDList varchar(8000)
  DECLARE @id int
  DECLARE @FinalTable TABLE (
    factid int,
    charid int
  )

  SET @CharIDList = CHAR(08) + @delimiter

  INSERT INTO @FinalTable
    SELECT DISTINCT
      @FactID,
      CharacterId
    FROM KeyFactsCharacters
    WHERE KeyFactID = @FactID

  WHILE ((SELECT
      COUNT(*)
    FROM @FinalTable)
    > 0)
  BEGIN

    SET @Id = (SELECT TOP 1
      charid
    FROM @FinalTable)

    SET @CharIDList = CAST(@CharIDList + @Id + @delimiter AS varchar(8000))

  END

  SET @CharIDList = CAST(@CharIDList + CHAR(08) + '~' AS varchar(8000))

  RETURN CAST(@CharIDList AS varchar(8000))
END
```

I invoke it using this:

```
SELECT dbo.FactPersonList(KeyFact.KeyFactId, '/') FROM KeyFactsCharacters, KeyFact
```

Comment: Which line are you getting the error?

Comment: I only get the error when I invoke it so it doesnt give me a line in the function. Is there a way to run the function directly?

Comment: You can create a temporary table in your function and store debug information.. it will help you to find where your code fails..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with MS SQL (experience almost exclusively in MySQL), but I would guess that `@CharIDList + @Id + @delimiter` is causing the error; since `@Id` is defined as an `int`, MS SQL may be trying to coerce the other operands to int values as well (for addition rather than concatenation).

Comment: Effing Genius. How did I miss that?